# Using import statement, why does it fail with "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier""

Tags: javascript, module

So I am trying to test out `import myFunction from './mymodules.js'`.
Opening in Chrome and I get the error - `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

here is the Repl: https://repl.it/@PaulThomas1/ModulePractice

I am looking at this article : https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/modules

My module class:

```
export default function findInArray(arr, search) {
  if(Array.isArray(arr) == false) return Error("arr - Is not an array");
  if(search == undefined) return Error("search - Undefined");

  let searchMethod;

  if(typeof search == 'string') {
      searchMethod = (element) => { 
        return search == element;
      };
    } else {
      searchMethod = (element) => {
        return search(element);
      };
    }

  arr.forEach(element => {
    if(searchMethod(element)) {
      return element;
    }
  });

  return '';
}
```

My Javascript that is trying to import this :

```
import findInArray from './modules/util.js';

let myArray = ["Bill", "Bob", "Ben"];

console.log(findInArray(myArray, "Bob"));
```

NOTE: In the Repl it recognizes the method from the import, but fails to run. 
I have read several gotcha pages, but nothing on this. 
Am I doing something obviously wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a couple of issues:

1) You only need to load in `script.js` since that calls in the other module (make sure `type="module"` is on that script tho)

```
<script type="module" src="script.js"></script>
```

2) In `util` you can't return from the callback of `forEach` like that. You should probably use either [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) or [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to return a new array or object instead depending on your requirements:

```
return arr.filter(element => searchMethod(element));
```

Comment: Ok, thanks Andy, the code was just a test, so I can scrap that. The consuming script has to be also marked module then?

Comment: Andy, made the edits to the HTML as advised and bingo. HUGE thanks. !!